# Sharp artifacts when using fill tool with mask in texture paint

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

##### Problem:

I want to understand the cause so I can avoid it in future, maybe even find some simple solution.

##### Steps:

I unwrapped my model using "smart UV". Islands do not touch, there is margin and I fixed overlaps (I had to adjust model in meantime).

I select desired faces in edit mode and enable mask in texture painting.
Then I fill specific region, it sometimes makes sharp edges that goes somewhere.
My only guess is that they want to connect adjecent faces?

###### Any solution?

Should I make seams from islands, will that fix it? It will make face selection harder for sure.

**Selection example:**
[image: Selection]

**Artifacts:**
[image: Artifacts]

**UV overview:**
[image: UV]

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem could be that you have your Bleed set to a point that it is looking for those connections even though your selection is mean to limit the projection of the paint. See if your Bleed is set over 4 pixels and reduce to 4 and see if it stops.[image]

Comment: I did not know this setting exist, I had 2px, but I think it could be the cause. I will look into it if it happens again, thanks for help :D